# The fragment shader material doesn’t stay with the object when we drag it around?

Tags: glsl, shader, fragment-shader, vertex-shader, babylonjs

How can I make the fragment shader material move with the ground/mesh when it is dragged around?
https://playground.babylonjs.com/#Q4P6QE

**Vertex Shader**:

```
precision highp float;

// Attributes
attribute vec3 position;
attribute vec2 uv;

// Uniforms
uniform mat4 worldViewProjection;

// Varying
varying vec2 vUV;

void main(void) {
    gl_Position = worldViewProjection * vec4(position, 1.0);

    vUV = uv;

    //I tried setting to get it work but Failed
    //vUV = (worldViewProjection * vec4(position, 1.0)).xy;
}
```

**FRAGMENT SHADER**:

```
#ifdef GL_ES
precision mediump float;
#endif

#define PI 3.14159265359

uniform vec2 resolution;
uniform float u_time;

float plot(vec2 st, float pct){
  return  smoothstep( pct-0.02, pct, st.y) -
          smoothstep( pct, pct+0.02, st.y);
}

void main() {
    vec2 st = gl_FragCoord.xy/resolution;

    // Step will return 0.0 unless the value is over 0.5,
    // in that case it will return 1.0
    float y = step(0.5,st.x);

    vec3 color = vec3(y);

    float pct = plot(st,y);
    color = (1.0-pct)*color+pct*vec3(0.0,1.0,0.0);

    gl_FragColor = vec4(color,1.0);
}
```

Is it because the custom vector shader is configured for world view projection?
Or do I need to set this explicitly using a function in Babylon.js?